# Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

Tags: java, sasl, apache-crunch, klist

***which credentials should be provided in kerebros for this exception to resolve when running apache crunch mapreduce pipleline?
No difference after logged in through kinit command. ***

Logs are as follows:

```
WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:{user_id} (auth:SIMPLE) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
2019-12-09 02:01:45 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
2019-12-09 02:01:45 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]

    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$700(RpcClientImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:741)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:862)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReaderImpl.restart(TableRecordReaderImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReaderImpl.initialize(TableRecordReaderImpl.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReader.initialize(TableRecordReader.java:134)
    at org.apache.crunch.io.hbase.inputformat.MultiTableInputFormatBase$1.initialize(MultiTableInputFormatBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void run() throws IOException {
            conn=ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
            return null;
        }
    });
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This worked for me :)